# VS 2015 Rebuild fails when shared project open in another running instance

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

In our environment, we have had some C# production processes running from the VS 2013 debugger on one of our development machines.  (Yes, yes we know this is not always such a good idea, but in this case, we needed a developer to monitor the processes and immediately take care of any issues that might arise.)

Since those processes were running on a development machine, there would often be times when the developer would need to rebuild another project he/she was working on.  Since we make use of a number of shared projects across our systems comprising data access layers, business layers, etc., a rebuild would require those shared projects to be rebuilt as well.

Under VS 2013, the rebuild would successfully complete without error and the developer would continue with his/her work.

However, since our switch to VS 2015, this is no longer the case. A rebuild of a solution that references any of the shared projects fails with the error(for example): Error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\DAL\obj\Debug\DAL.dll' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\DAL\obj\Debug\DAL.dll' is denied.'

The only solution has been to stop each of the running processes referencing the shared projects and then do the rebuild.

What seems very strange about this is that the failed copy is in the **obj** folder and not the bin folder.

We've tried switching back and forth with the VS Host debugging but the only solution so far has been to exit the other processes and perform the rebuild.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to solve this?

Thanks,

Eugene

Comment: You might need to check "Edit and Continue" feature as sometimes it's causing described locks. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164926.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but we have it checked already.  Any other ideas would be appreciated.